# Ubuntu service Upstart or SystemD, Django development server as Service

Tags: django, ubuntu, celery, systemd, upstart

I've been working around with Python & Django Framework for a while with Ubuntu 16.01. Since I used Django with Q system (Celery) and some others Enhancement Apps. When I try to run all the apps each time, I need to run development server "{python manage.py runserver}", then running Celery Worker "{celery -A filename worker -l info}". Each time I working, it takes me minutes to enter the directory and start it up. I surf around and come up with the idea of setup it as service. Example, service name: "pyd". 
I just need to run "{sudo pyd start}" -> then Django Development Server and Celery will start, and if I run "{sudo pyd stop}" -> then Django & Celery will stop.

I try to search around, and things start to confuse me between "Upstart" and "Systemd".

Could any one suggest, me how to make both Django and Celery as Service run in Ubuntu ? between "Upstart" & "Systemd" which one is better ??

Source code to indicate sample is appreciated.

Thank

Comment: check [immortal](https://immortal.run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Upstart to do this.

Post installation, go to the directory `/etc/init/`.
Create a file `xyz.conf` and add the lines:

```
cd /path/to/your/manage.py/file
exec python manage.py runserver & celery -A filename worker -l info
```

If you are using a virtualenv, add the following lines before the above:

```
pre-start script
    #activate virtual environment
    source env-name/bin/activate
end script
```

Now, you can start Django Dev Server and Celery as a service by issuing the commands, `sudo start xyz`, stop it by issuing `sudo stop xyz` and check status of your service by issuing `sudo status xyz`.

`xyz.conf` will log into `/var/log/upstart/xyz.log`. You can view logs with the following command: `sudo tail -f /var/log/upstart/xyz.log`.

Comment: I already try, what you said. It still not working. {{sudo start x1}}

I try to check the terminal, it said: "Job Failed to Start"

I try to check the syntax with "init-checkconf x1": syntax is OK.

Syntax

Comment: Content:

chdir  Desktop/NewFolder

exec  python manage runserver

I used "chdir" since "cd" show error.

Comment: Are you sure, your Upstart installation is correct?
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Comment: I've been checking with it.

Comment: If I run  { script  cd /home/x7/Desktop/Rest_API_v1.1/
  exec python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 end script  }, process is working fine.
 But if I run { script  cd /home/x7/Desktop/Rest_API_v1.1/
  exec python manage.py runserver  end script  }, it will not working.

Comment: Any suggestion to this is appreciate ??

Comment: What does it say, when it fails? Anything particular?

Comment: It said that "Service is running" for both of them, seem no problem
I try to check  the port with "netstat -lnt", no not showing and service in browser is not working with Django service.
and if I try with { script cd /home/x7/Desktop/Rest_API_v1.1/ exec python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 end script }, it run as normal.
I follow this reference https://blog.frd.mn/how-to-set-up-proper-startstop-services-ubuntu-debian-mac-windows/  , along with your answer, still I cannot start it as service. If you have any concise reference to suggest is appreciated.

Comment: Start your service, and view the log files. Share your logs. 
You can find it here: sudo tail -f /var/log/upstart/xyz.log

Comment: Finally, it works. Accidently, tried to change from systemvinit to upstart. After that I once Restart the Machine. Really, Thank you

Comment: Could you suggest me one, I am about the host the project of Django.
To handle large amount of users, between Nginx and Apache. Which one you think it's good to go with ????

Comment: I have successfully deployed multiple django applications with nginx, as well as apache. I personally found nginx's configurations very clean, easy to write and edit. I think you should consider looking at either nginx with gunicorn or nginx with uwsgi.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup celery as daemon service, follow the below steps

**Step 1: celery init script**

Copy this [script](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd) file in the directory /etc/init.d/celeryd (celeryd will be the service name, you can name it anything)

The instruction to set this up is given in the above source.

**Step 2: Setting up celery configuration**

Now configure celery configuration in this file /etc/default/celeryd, this [example](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#generic-systemd-celery-example) will give you a generic configuration file.

Now you can run celery as service with following commands

```
sudo service celeryd start

sudo service celeryd stop
```

or any other service commands.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: It really helpful, but anyways, have you ever try to use Ubuntu Upstart, to make app service. I working with Django, I want it to be as service by just type commandline: "sudo start djservice", -> then Django start, without no need to type "python manage.py runserver"