# Supervisord (exit status 2; not expected) ubuntu

Tags: celery, ubuntu-16.04, supervisord

I'm trying to run Celery with Supervisord on Ubuntu, but am getting:

```
INFO exited: celery (exit status 2; not expected)
INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 15517
INFO gave up: celery entered FATAL state, too many start retries too 
quickly
```

This is the Supervisord script:

```
cd into the directory and activate the virtual environment 
celery -A [APP_NAME].celery worker -E -l info --concurrency=2
```

If I run this script manually, Celery starts up without any issues. But running `sudo supervisorctl start celery` errors out with the error messages above.

Comment: sorry I was also unsuccessful setting up as supervisord, i set it up as service refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46936442/5068345

Comment: I'll probably end up using systemd for this. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Can you please post your supervisord config?